# Creating custom metrics in tensorflow estimators

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am training a classification problem using tensorflow estimators.

I want to calculate the f1 score for each batch to data along with precision and recall.

I calculate precision and recall using the code below and log them for evaluation and training.

I also calculate the fscore using the formula, but while logging the fscore I get an error.

```
pre = tf.metrics.precision(labels=labels,predictions=pred,name="precision")

rec = tf.metrics.recall(labels=labels,predictions=pred,name="recall")

fscore_val = tf.reduce_mean((2*pre[0]*rec[0]) / (pre[0] + rec[0] + 1e-5))
fscore_update = tf.group(pre[1], rec[1])

fscore = (fscore_val, fscore_update)

# logging metric at evaluation time
metrics['precision'] = pre                    
metrics['recall'] = rec
metrics['fscore'] = fscore 

# logging metric at training time                   
tf.summary.scalar('precision', pre[1])
tf.summary.scalar('recall', rec[1])
tf.summary.scalar('fscore', fscore)
```

This is the error that I get.

```
TypeError: Expected float32, got <tf.Operation 'metrics_Left_Lane_Type/group_deps' type=NoOp> of type 'Operation' instead.
```

I understand why I am getting this error.
It is because fscore should be two values, similar to precision and recall.

Can someone please help me on how to do this in tensorflow estimators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, TensorFlow has it's own f1 score `tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score` and it is rather straightforward to use. The only possible downside is that it hides threshold value from user, choosing the best from specified quantity of possible thresholds.

```
predictions = tf.sigmoid(logits)
tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score(labels, predictions, num_thresholds=20)
```

If, for any reason, you want a custom implementation, you need to group `update_ops`. Every TensorFlow metric has operation that increments its value. You can set threshold manually when defining predictions

```
predictions = tf.greater(tf.sigmoid(logits), 0.5)
```

```py
def f1_score(labels, predictions):
    precision, update_op_precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels, predictions)
    recall, update_op_recall = tf.metrics.recall(labels, predictions)
    eps = 1e-5 #small constant for numerical stability
    f1 = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall + eps)
    f1_upd = 2 * update_op_precision * update_op_recall / (update_op_precision + update_op_recall + eps)
    return f1, f1_upd

f1_score = f1_score(labels, predictions)
```

Then you can add it to `eval_metric_ops` dict or pass to `summary.scalar`

```
eval_metric_ops = {'f1': f1_score}
tf.summary.scalar('f1', f1_score[1])
```

It actually gives very close results with metric from contrib module

Comment: Thanks,,,I will try it out

Comment: It works,,,Thanks a lot...I was missing the tf.group step

Comment: found an error...evaluation fscore is logged properly but training is not...gives an error.

Comment: ```TypeError: Expected float32, got <tf.Operation 'fscore' type=NoOp> of type 'Operation' instead```

Comment: You obviously passed operation instead of value somewhere. please update your answer with relevant code.

Comment: I have updated the question with the changes you suggested and along with the error. please have a look

Comment: I also tried "tf.summary.scalar('fscore', fscore[0])" The code runs after that but does not log correct fscore for training. It does a good job for evaluation step

Comment: I also tried "tf.summary.scalar('fscore', fscore[1])" it gives an error "TypeError: Can't convert Operation 'metrics_Left_Lane_Type/group_deps' to Tensor (target dtype=None, name=u'values', as_ref=False)"

Comment: Ok, either smth changed in the API, or I jusst messed up. The code that i gave in my answer was for low level api actually, and I thought I used it with Estimator sometime ago, but I forgot. So, looks like you can just use the same math with update ops in estimator. Updated answer. Compared with f1 from contrib, shows almost the same result